# Customize Parallax in MaterializeCss

Tags: parallax, materialize

I am trying to implement parallax effect in materialize framework http://materializecss.com/parallax.html in my project. I have been able to initialize and implement it. 
How can I customize the speed of background image and content over it.

Here's my code :

```
<section class="parallax-container">
        <div class="parallax"><img src="/static/images/home/img_background.jpg">
        </div>
        <h2 class="header">Parallax</h2>
        <p class="grey-text">This is going to be my content over image.</p>
</section>
```

Parallax Initialization :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.parallax').parallax();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not the best solution, but you can change the parallax scroll distance in materialize.js:

```
var parallax = Math.round((parallax_dist * percentScrolled));
```

for example with a multiplier:

```
var parallax = Math.round((parallax_dist * percentScrolled * 0.3));
```